# Dates and writing a line based on what day they are born

Tags: c#, datetime

This is my Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Date of Birth");

    Console.WriteLine("Year");
    int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Month");
    int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Day");
    int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    DateTime DOB = new DateTime(year, month, day);

    Console.WriteLine("You were born on a " + DOB.DayOfWeek);
    if (DOB.DayOfWeek == Monday)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mondays Child");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I keep getting this message when running it

> "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.DayOfWeek' and 'string'"

Anybody know what I need to do?

Comment: Do not change your question [like that](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32052490/3). It _might_ be helpful for future readers. If these answers solved your problem, you can upvote them and/or select as an answer one of them.

Comment: please dont remove all your question. it can help others later.

Comment: Your code as it stands will not produce the error that you posted. This can be misleading to a newbie. When you were running your code you must have had  if (DOB.DayOfWeek == "Monday") instead of  if (DOB.DayOfWeek == Monday).

Comment: @thewisegod i think OP was trying to use `enum` . since you cant use enum with only its value OP may changed it to string to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
DOB.DayOfWeek == Monday
```

should be

```
DOB.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your if condition to the following one:

```
if (DOB.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

The `DayOfWeek`  property of a `DateTime`

> Gets the day of the week represented by this instance.

This has a value of the constants in the `DayOfWeek` enumeration. Hence you can't compare an int, which is the underlying type of this enumeration, with a string.

For further information about this enumeration, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx).